# How to create local repository using subversion eclipse plugin which is available to multiple users

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I have a selenium web driver + Eclipse project code in a folder in my local C drive.

I want to share it other users using Eclipse. How can I do that?

I tried to add eclipse subversion plugin but I am not able to create a repository in my local.

Comment: have you added the plugin eventually ??

Answer (score 1):

With TortoiseSVN you can create a repository, configuring users, passwords in different groups. Then, you can connect to this repository to Eclipse through Subclipse Plugin

[Chapter 3. The Repository](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html)

Comment: the repository u told to create can be used by multiple users ??